# How to write long numbers as text with interop.excel

Tags: c#, excel

I am  using `interop.excel` dll and creating an Excel file. I am having issues while writing long numbers as text.

Below is the code I am using. I can use apostrophe, but if you look in formula bar, you can see the cell is formatted.

Is there any other way of writing long numbers to an Excel spreadsheet without seeing the formatted value in the formula bar (using `numberformat`)?

```
worksheet.Cells[i, j] = "'" + dr[p];

//var startCell = (Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[i, j]; 

//var endCell = (Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[i, j]; 

//worksheetRange = worksheet.get_Range(startCell, endCell); 

//worksheetRange.NumberFormat = "#####";
```

Comment: did you try to use cell.NumberFormat = "@"?

Comment: Thanks it worked. I wasn't using numberformat with right syntax

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do it in one line, you could use the [Text function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx).

Example:

```
worksheets.Cells[i, j] = "=Text(" + dr[p] + ", \"#\"";
```

But that probably isn't what you're looking for because this would store the number as a text and display the formula in the formula bar. In that case, like user194076 suggested, you could use `.NumberFormat = "@";` 
or `.NumberFormat = "#";` if you don't want it to show in scientific notation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NumberFormat with '@' or '#'
Example:

```
Range r= worksheet.Cells;
r.NumberFormat = "@";
```